# How to _scrape_ specific url inside page of a website using BeautfulSoup in python notebook

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am scraping a website for educational learning purpose.
My question is how to **scrape** a url link inside a particular page of a website.
example:[see this link](https://bcorporation.net/directory/danone-specialized-nutrition-mellin-sp-a-and-nutricia-italia-sp-a)
it contains a url below the image.
Thats exctly my point is, to catch that link for every page.
I tried this one but it didn't work:
    `Websitelist=soup.find_all('div',class_='field-item even') itemz='field-item even' for tmp in Websitelist: for link in tmp.find_all('a',href=True): print(Websitelist)`

I have attached a sample pic of it's inspect element code.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQSD4.png)
Note: class name is not specific , meaning it is used more than once in the inspect element code.
I tried alot over the internet but couldn't figure it out.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the perfect answer**
What it's doing

1. Finding all `div` elements with class `even`
2. Making a new list of divs if the div has `a` as a child and that `a` has `href` attribute.
3. Printing the `href` attribute

```py
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="even")
a = [i.find("a") for i in divs if i.find("a") and i.find("a").has_attr("href")]
print(a[0]['href'])
>>> http://www.corporate.danone.it
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse, i want to fetch the url from the clickable text. Please refer to the image attached above it will clearify everything.

Comment: Thank you again for replying but unfortunately this isn't relevant to my idea. My point is if you visit this site https://bcorporation.net/directory/greening-sp-a
you will find WWW.GREENING-RCA.CL/ below the company logo 
I wnt this button url to be fetched by my program, html code can be viewed here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQSD4.png

I hope you answer it.

Comment: waiting for your kind response

Comment: i tested my code for that website and it works and gives the url that is url of that button `http://www.greening-rca.cl/`